# string.clear() does not remove element properly

Tags: c++, string, undefined-behavior

It seems that member function `clear()` of string does remove its content, but the removed contents still can be accessed by `operator[]` . Here's the example that makes me confused.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string input = "Weird";
    cout << "Your Input: " << input << "\n";
    input.clear();
    cout << "Your Input: " << input << "\n";
    cout << "Your Input: " << input[0] << input[1] << input[2] << input[3] << input[4] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
Your Input: Weird
Your Input:
Your Input: eird
```

Why this is happenning? If example above is normal, what should I do to completely remove its content? (accessing by input[1] should be '\000')

Comment: Undefined behavior sometimes looks like it's working, even when it isn't.

Comment: If you are adamant about the string *actually* being empty after a call to `.clear()` call `.shrink_to_fit()`.

Comment: @Casey No, that does not work any better. The string *is* actually empty. What OP does is invalid. Calling `.shrink_to_fit()` doesn’t change that.

Comment: *what should I do to completely remove its content?* -- Why should it matter to you what the junk is at the logical of the string happens to be?  If it's 0, the letter `a`, or some other crazy character, why should it be a concern?  You shouldn't attempt to index into that area anyway.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that is because when I get string through cin in a loop, (like cin >> input)  some leftover element can still be accessed even if I clear() it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  One more thing to add, I encountered this kind of problem while solving problems on an algorithm training site.

Comment: @YHCho But *what* is the problem here? `clear()` does the correct thing, as long as you write valid code. If this scenario poses a problem for you, you have a bug in your code (such as accessing values out of bound).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah you have a point. At least I have to be careful not to wirte a code like a loop containing both `clear()` and accessing through `operator[]`

Comment: This isn't much different from `int arr[5];` and then accessing `arr[6];`. The C++ compiler trusts you-the-programmer to not operate out-of-bounds and generates the most efficient code that it can assuming that you will not. Don't betray that trust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing elements of a string after calling the method `clear` invokes undefined behavior.

It seems in your case the class `std::string` uses its internal buffer defined within the class itself for short strings.

After the call of `clear` the class just set the first character of the buffer with the terminating zero character `'\0;`.

To check that string was cleared just output its length as for example

```
std::cout << input.length() << '\n';
```

Comment: It does not matter if `std::string` is using an internal buffer or not.  It's not uncommon for deallocated buffers to hold their former contents for a brief period of time.

Comment: @m The C++ Standard does not define what will be with the dynamically allocated buffer in this case..

Comment: The standard doesn't require a previously allocated buffer to be freed when `clear()` is called. It's entirely valid for the string to set the size to 0 and make sure that the `[]` operator does return `'\0'` when accessing the first element while leaving the capacity unchanged.

Comment: @fabian it's not even required for the string indexing to return `'\0'`, that's only required for `.c_str()`.

Comment: @MarkRansom true, but I would find it very curious if c_str()[0] reported '\0' and [0] didn't. Do you know of any such string implementation?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I don't know of any such implementation, and I wouldn't expect to find one - by far the easiest way to make `c_str` do the right thing is to already have the `'\0'` at the end of the buffer.  But I hate to tempt those nasal demons; any access at or beyond the length of the string is undefined behavior no matter what.